# php continues to output to csv file after fclose

Tags: php, csv

I am writing some data into a CSV file using the below code and finally closing with fclose() and after the i am redirecting to destination page but instead of redirecting echo content is getting printed into the downloaded CSV.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $cvs_cols);
fclose($out);
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"File Partially Uploaded. Please Check error log!\");
            window.location = \"destination_file.php\"
          </script>";
```

Why is it that echo content gets into the CSV download file when it has already fclose()? once the data has been written to csv, I want to redirect the page in the browser. How can I do that?

Comment: `'php://output'` is where all output from a php script goes. Try writing the csv to a in memory text, or a file and then sending it when you want it sent

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you provide me an example